# ubuntu 22.04 - phpmyadmin not working

Tags: server, 22.04, phpmyadmin, localhost

On Ubuntu 22.04, after installing `apache`, `php`, `mysql` and `phpmyadmin`, the link http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ returns a blank page.
The only code outputted is:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;

if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // phpcs:enable
}

global $route, $containerBuilder;

require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';

$dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
Routing::callControllerForRoute($route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me get `phpmyadmin` running.

Comment: here a solution you need to enable php fhm. was facing the same : https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=httpd&f=7

Answer (score 4):

> returns a blank page. The only code outputted

is the PHP code returned from the page and not executed ?

if yes, seems like you did not install libapache2-mod-php(version), where version is your PHP version, i.e for PHP 8.1:

> sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1

after that, reload the apache :

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

and try to access `phpmyadmin`

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Looks simple, but in my case, after updating Ubuntu to 22.4 LTS, my `phpmyadmin` stopped working. Problem was the Apache server that was not running at all. So it's important to check if your Apache is doing well first using this command:

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I upgraded my google server from ubuntu 20.04lts to 22.04lts

when I checked the version of the php installed, it was php8.2 but all the guides online talk about 8.1 and installing sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1, instead I did this:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.2
```

and then

```
a2query -m php8.2
```

And problem solved!!

Hope this helps